# How to show error if client did not click check, but with not default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to show error message if client did not click checkbox, but it shows the error message by default.
How do I manage to show it only after submission?

```
const InputForm=()=>{
    const [value ,setValue] = useState("");
    const [check,setCheck] = useState(null)

    const getValue=(e)=>{
        setValue(e.target.value);
    }

    const getCheck=(e)=>{
        setCheck(e.target.checked);
    }

    const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const emailValidator =/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
        if (value.match(emailValidator)) {
            console.log("Valid");
        }else{
            console.log("Invalid");
        }
        
    };

    return(
        <form className="inputForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="tos" >
                <label className="container">
                    <span>I agree to <strong>terms of service</strong></span>
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={getCheck}/>
                    <span className="checkmark" ></span>
                </label>
                <p style={check?{display:"none"}:{display:"block",color:"red"}}>You must accept the terms and conditions</p>
            </div>
            <Footer/>
        </form>
    )
};
```

Comment: do you want message to appear once user check and uncheck?

Comment: @cmgchess yes, I want to show message if user did not click and remove once it clicked, but do not want to show message once page uploaded 1st time

Comment: You mean you don't want to show ```<p>``` tag on initial render?

Comment: @YashSharma Correct

Comment: You set ```check``` to ```null``` which evaluates to ```false``` and that's why the ternary operator you used in ```<p>``` is evaluating to ```false``` and ```<p>``` element is getting ```display:' block' ```styling and it's rendering on initial render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    checked && setError(false);
  }, [checked, setError]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!checked) {
      setError(true);
    } else {
      // do what you want
    }
  };

  return (
    <form className="inputForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="tos">
        <label className="container">
          <span>
            I agree to <strong>terms of service</strong>
          </span>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={(e) => setChecked(e.target.checked)}
          />
          <span className="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        {error && (
          <p style={{ color: "red" }}>
            You must accept the terms and conditions
          </p>
        )}
      </div>

      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a solution :
https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-field-m6j5h?file=/src/App.js

You should have a separate state for the error and render the message only if that state is truthy.
That state should be set when calling you handleSubmit function.
To remove the error message when the checkbox is checked, you can listen to it in a useEffect hook.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was thinking about could not realize how to write it.

Comment: On a side note, you should check react-hook-form, that library is amazing!

Comment: thanks for the hook recommendation, as long as I am new to React, I have no much info about different hooks.